# How to call nested values with the Param annotation in JPA?

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I implemented a method but it has so many parameters in the method definition like:

```
@Query("...")
public List<Result> getResults(
   @Param("a") String a, 
@Param("b") String b, 
@Param("c") String c, 
@Param("d") String d, 
@Param("e") String e, 
@Param("f") String f );
```

The problem is that I can only add four parameters to the method, how can I pass the e and f parameters?

I think the solution is to pass the parameters grouped in an object, like:

```
@Query(" ... :params.e ... :params.f ...")
public List<Result> getResults(
   @Param("params") Parameters params );
```

How can I achieve this using JPA, can you answer with an example?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose try to use spel like solution below

```
@Query("... = :#{#params.e}")
public List<Result> getResults(@Param("params") Parameters params);
```

In Parameters class add what you want to use in query.

Hope useful.

Comment: works fine! A shame that a quick Google search doesn't reveal more information though